# how to reply a photo with caption in nodejs telegram bot (telegraf)

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm writing a telegram bot with [telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/).
I want to send a photo with a text under it in the reply message.
I have written this:

```
    serviceDetailsScene.on('callback_query', async ({replyWithPhoto}) => {
        await replyWithPhoto({url: <url>})
}
```

It works and sends image properly, but I don't know how to append the message to it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this for replying with image src and caption:

```
bot.hears('photo', ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: <pic-src> }, { caption: "cat photo" });
```

And if you want to send image url you can write this:

```
bot.hears('photo', ctx.replyWithPhoto({ url: <pic-url> }, { caption: "cat photo" });
```

Comment: Is it possible to add markdown formatting to the caption?

Comment: How to send reply with multiple photos?

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
await replyWithPhoto({url: <url>}, {caption: 'Your caption'})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.